# Read lines with specific characteristics from a file, exclude all others line

Tags: java, file-io

I am trying to write method to read lines with some specification from a file. for Example,

my text file contains following:--

```
12-01-01 13:26 San Jose 12.99 DVD
12-12-30 09:40 Miami 13.50 Music
14-08-30 10:20 Arizona 16.03 Scientist
11-07-10 09:10 New York 25.00 ColdPlay
14-08-30 10:20 Arizona 18.04 MeetYou
14-08-30 10:20 Arizona 50.03 Scientist
11-07-10 09:30 New York 25.00 ColdPlay
11-07-10 09:20 New York 25.00 ColdPlay
```

tab separated values, for different columns and these are the lines only I want method to read.
Now suppose if any is there as below, or even enter

```
12-01-01 13:26 San Jose 12.99 DVD
12-12-30 09:40 Miami 13.50 Music
14-08-30 10:20 Arizona 16.03 Scientist
11-07-10 09:10 New York 25.00 ColdPlay
14-08-30 10:20 Arizona 18.04 MeetYou
[new lines]
14-08-30 10:20 Arizona 50.03 Scientist
11-07-10 09:30 New York 25.00 ColdPlay
//This line should not be read
even this should not be read #$%^&
11-07-10 09:20 New York 25.00 ColdPlay
```

That particular line should be escaped. Till now I have done when the file format is proper, and it is as below:--

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     BufferedReader br = null;
     String temp = null;
     List<String> arrayRead = new ArrayList<String>();
     try{
         br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:\\testing\\SalesData.txt"));
         while((temp=br.readLine())!= null){
             arrayRead.add(temp);
         }
         int n = arrayRead.size();
         System.out.println("No. of Records in file "+n);
        //Add arrayList data to String Array
         String[] linesToRead = arrayRead.toArray(new String[arrayRead.size()]);

         String[] lineX = null;
         Hashtable<String, String> dataReq = new Hashtable<String, String>();
         for(int i=0; i<arrayRead.size(); i++){
             lineX = linesToRead[i].split("\\t");
             dataReq.put(lineX[2], lineX[3]);
         }

     }
     catch(FileNotFoundException f){
         f.printStackTrace();
     }
     catch(IOException e){
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
     finally{
         if(br!= null){
             try {
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Did i get this right: you want to extract the text (e.g. "Arizona") and the price (or whatever is in the following column) from your file ignoring anything which is not of that format?

Answer (score 0):

Why not [regex](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/)? Can be useful.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

public class MyLineReader {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File inputFile = new File("myfile.txt");

        // Create pattern object.
        String pattern = "^(\\d{2}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}\\s\\d{2}:\\d{2})\\s([a-zA-Z\\s]*)\\s(\\d*\\.?\\d*)\\s(\\w*)$";
        ArrayList<String[]> collectedLines = new ArrayList<String[]>();
        Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

        // Match those.
        Matcher m;
        FileInputStream fis = null;

        try{
            fis = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
            Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(fis);
            String line;
            String[] row;

            while (fileScanner.hasNextLine()){
                line = fileScanner.nextLine();
                m = r.matcher(line);

                if (m.find()) {

                    // Regex have groups.
                    row = new String[] { m.group(1), m.group(2), m.group(3), m.group(4) };

                    collectedLines.add ( row );
                        System.out.println ( String.format("Date: %s, Name: %s, Decimal: %s, Last: %s", row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3]));
                    }
                }
        }catch(IOException ex){
            System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
        }finally {
            if (fis != null){
                try{
                    fis.close();
                }catch(Exception ex){
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

The regular expression used is the following, you can check regex online [here](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html):

```
String pattern = "^(\\d{2}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}\\s\\d{2}:\\d{2})\\s([a-zA-Z\\s]*)\\s(\\d*\\.?\\d*)\\s(\\w*)$";
```